# Bash Script to download list of identifier and save to file

Tags: bash

I want to write a bash script to download the list of identifier and save to a file.
inside the file metadata.xml i have

```html
<ListIdentifiers>
    <header>
      <identifier>demo:HASH01d242dc3e08e1fdcf7343bb</identifier>
      <datestamp>2009-03-01</datestamp>
      <setSpec>demo</setSpec>
    </header>
    <header>
      <identifier>demo:HASHa84b11354e321524fd5ef6</identifier>
      <datestamp>2009-03-01</datestamp>
      <setSpec>demo</setSpec>
    </header>
    <header>
      <identifier>demo:HASHa891721179ce8bc74b905a</identifier>
      <datestamp>2009-03-01</datestamp>
      <setSpec>demo</setSpec>
    </header>
 </ListIdentifiers>
```

Inside my bash script, I have code that finds all the identifier and stored them in an array. Then I want to loop through all the identifier and download metadata records for each identifier and store in a separate directory.
The metadata is in the format

```html
demo:HASH01d242dc3e08e1fdcf7343bb
demo:HASHa84b11354e321524fd5ef6
```

I want to split the metadata and use for example HASH01d242dc3e08e1fdcf7343bb.xml to name the metadata files that were download

My code downloaded the metadata but it doesn't name the file correctly, instead of naming the file, for example, HASH01d242dc3e08e1fdcf7343bb.xml it name it as oaiserver?verb=GetRecord&identifier=demo:HASH01d242dc3e08e1fdcf7343bb&metadataPrefix=oai_dc.xml which is not what I want.

How to fix my code so that all the metadata that was download has a file name that resembles its identifier for example HASH01d242dc3e08e1fdcf7343bb.xml,HASHa84b11354e321524fd5ef6.xml and so fort.

```html
myarray=($(grep identifier metadata.xml|tr -d ' ' | sed 's/<[^>]*>//g' ))
for i in "${myarray[@]}"; do wget -P test/ "http://www.nzdl.org/cgi-bin/oaiserver?verb=GetRecord&identifier="$i"&metadataPrefix=oai_dc"| cut -d":" -f2; done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to fix my code so that all the metadata that was download has a file name that resembles its identifier

You have to tell `wget` not to write the output to a file it sees as appropriate, but rather to the standard output, and redirect the output of `cut` to your desired file:

```
for i in "${myarray[@]}"
do  wget -O - "http://…" |
    cut -d: -f2 >test/$i.xml
done
```

If by "I want to split the metadata" you meant the metadata identifiers rather than the downloaded metadata records, then the output doesn't need to be changed, just the identifier:

```
for i in "${myarray[@]}"
do  wget -O test/${i/*:}.xml "http://…"
done
```

Comment: Thanks, i did it out to file but the file name still name as demo:HASH4632a8a51d33c47a75c559.xml. I want to split the string so that the file is named as HASH4632a8a51d33c47a75c559.xml without the demo

Comment: When you wrote "_I want to split the metadata_", did you mean the metadata identifiers rather than the downloaded metadata records? I'll add a version for that case.